# Object being changed by returning value?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

This is very basic, but I don't understand why when I do:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    Rectangle *myRect = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
    XYPoint *myPoint = [[XYPoint alloc] init];

    [myPoint setX:100 andY:200];

    [myRect setWidth:5 andHeigth:8];
    myRect.origin = myPoint;

    NSLog(@"Origin at (%i, %i)", myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y);


    [myPoint setX:50 andY:50];
    NSLog(@"Origin at (%i, %i)", myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y);

    XYPoint *theOrigin = myRect.origin;

    theOrigin.x = 200;
    theOrigin.y = 300;

     NSLog(@"Origin at (%i, %i)", myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y);

}
return 0;
}
```

the origin of my rectangle changes. Here is the output:

```
Origin at (100, 200)
Origin at (100, 200)
Origin at (200, 300)
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

But if I did something like:

```
int a, b;
a = 5;
b = 6;
b = a;
```

the value of a would stay 5 and b would change to 6.

I thought the value on the right side of the equal sign never changes, but sets the value on the left side of the equal sign. So why when I do:

```
XYPoint *theOrigin = myRect.origin;

    theOrigin.x = 200;
    theOrigin.y = 300;
```

Why does the value of myRect.origin change? theOrigin is a pointer, so why does changing the value of the pointer change the object to which it points (myRect)? My book says the "return value is vulnerable." What does that mean? If I wanted to make a copy inside the method myRect.origin so that by doing:

```
XYPoint *theOrigin = myRect.origin;

    theOrigin.x = 200;
    theOrigin.y = 300;
```

the value of myRect.origin doesn't change?

Comment: See _my_ book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html#_instance_references_and_assignment

Comment: You would have to show the declaration and implementation of the `Rectangle` and `XYPoint` classes for us to know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"does the value of myRect.origin change?"

Yes, because you are modifying the same object. `XYPoint *theOrigin` is a pointer to an object, and it points to the same object as `myRect.origin` (which is also a pointer.) I would suggest reading a little about pointers, that will help you understand this behavior. (Don't worry, pointers themselves are pretty simple.)

Comment: Thanks tons! I'll read about those. What object do theOrigin and myRect.origin point to? Also: I edited my question and asked how I could edit the method to make a copy. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: "What object do theOrigin and myRect.origin point to?" Can't answer this exactly, without knowing more about `Rectangle`. In general terms though, they point to an instance of `XYPoint`, that I would guess was allocated in `-[Rectangle init]`.

Comment: "how I could edit the method to make a copy" You would define the implementation of the property getter for `origin`, e.g.: `- (XYPoint *)origin() { return [_origin copy]; }`. (And, if `origin` is `@synthesize`d you would remove that.)